# Read a specific value from a json file with Python

Tags: python, json, curl

I am getting a JSON file from a curl request and I want to read a specific value from it.
Suppose that I have a JSON file, like the following one. How can I insert the "result_count" value into a variable?

[image: An example of a JSON file]

Currently, after getting the response from curl, I am writing the JSON objects into a txt file like this.

```
json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)

f.write(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data in your questions, put them in it as text so others can use it.

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `json_response`  isn't a JSON content (JSON is a formatted string), but a `python dict`, you can access it using the keys

```
res_count = json_response['meta']['result_count']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` module from the python standard library.
`data` itself is just a python dictionary, and can be accessed as such.

```py
import json

with open('path/to/file/filename.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

result_count = data['meta']['result_count']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse a JSON string using `json.loads()` method in `json` module.

```
response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)
json_response = json.load(response)
```

after that you can extract an element with specify element name in Brackets

```
result_count = ['meta']['result_count']
```